# How to set data values on Kendo Multi Select?

Tags: jquery, telerik, kendo-ui

I'm using a Kendo Multi Select. I want to load selected values into the multi select. How do you set the data values in Java Script? I have the following script:

```
$('#selectedFilters').kendoMultiSelect({
                    dataSource: data,
                    dataTextField: 'name',
                    dataValueField: 'value',
                    filter: 'contains',
                    placeholder: "Add Filter",
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 2,
                    highlightFirst: true,
                    ignoreCase: true,
                    change: function (event) {
                        applyFilters();
                    },
                });
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`value()`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/multiselect#methods-value) method for setting the values.

Example, give the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="button" class="k-button">Select</a>
<input id='selectedFilters'>
```

and the JavaScript:

```
var data = [
    { name : "name1", value : "value1" },
    { name : "name2", value : "value2" },
    { name : "name3", value : "value3" },
    { name : "name4", value : "value4" },
    { name : "name5", value : "value5" },
    { name : "name6", value : "value6" }
];
var multiselect = $('#selectedFilters').kendoMultiSelect({
    dataSource    : data,
    dataTextField : 'name',
    dataValueField: 'value',
    filter        : 'contains',
    placeholder   : "Add Filter",
    delay         : 0,
    minLength     : 2,
    highlightFirst: true,
    ignoreCase    : true,
    change        : function (event) {
        console.log("change");
    }
}).data("kendoMultiSelect");

$("#button").on("click", function () {
    console.log("multiselect", multiselect);
    multiselect.value(["value1", "value2", "value6"]);
});
```

If you click on `button` the multi-value `input` gets: `name1`, `name2` and `name6`.

**EDIT** If you want to add to current selected values then do:

```
$("#button").on("click", function () {
    var selected = multiselect.value();
    var res = $.merge($.merge([], selected), ["value1", "value2", "value6"]);
    multiselect.value(res);
});
```

**NOTE**: For some sort of reason you cannot reuse `selected` array for setting new values, so you should create a new one.

Check it running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/LQx2z/)

Comment: How would you append a single selection?

Comment: Instead of an array use a string: `multiselect.value("value1")`

Comment: No, I meant if I have 5 items selected and I want to append a 6th item. Who would I do that?

Comment: .select() is not a method in version 2013.1.319 of KendoUI.

Comment: @Rodney, for some sort of reason you cannot reuse the original array for setting new values, so you should do `var res = $.merge($.merge([], selected), ["value1", "value2", "value6"]);` and then `multiselect.value(res)` Check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/LQx2z/)

Comment: Beware as OnaBai found out: You cannot simply push an element to the array returned by calling .value()!!!!! Why??? This took me hours to figure out and still makes no sense to me...

Comment: @Rodney, Thanks. I Should have just asked you sense you sit 2 cubes down from me :).

Comment: @OnaBai I used same function and my selected values res = (2) ["3333333", "1000001XX"] like this but still i couldn't show in multiselection

Answer (score 1):

there is a easier way to do this. all kendo controls have a rich client side API. So here is the API documentation page of MultiSelect - http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/multiselect

Now coming to your problem - here is my solution:

Markup:

```
<select id="required" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select attendees...">
            <option>Steven White</option>
            <option>Nancy King</option>
            <option>Anne King</option>
            <option>Nancy Davolio</option>
            <option>Robert Davolio</option>
            <option>Michael Leverling</option>
            <option>Andrew Callahan</option>
            <option>Michael Suyama</option>
            <option>Anne King</option>
            <option>Laura Peacock</option>
            <option>Robert Fuller</option>
            <option>Janet White</option>
            <option>Nancy Leverling</option>
            <option>Robert Buchanan</option>
            <option>Margaret Buchanan</option>
            <option>Andrew Fuller</option>
            <option>Anne Davolio</option>
            <option>Andrew Suyama</option>
            <option>Nige Buchanan</option>
            <option>Laura Fuller</option>
        </select>
```

JavaScript:

```
// create MultiSelect from select HTML element
var required = $("#required").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");
```

Now in order to set the selected values for the select box, you just have to use the value() method. Here is the code:
To set single value:

```
required.value("Laura Fuller")
```

To set multiple value:

```
required.value(["Laura Fuller","Laura Peacock"]);
```

Now to clear the values you just set empty string as the value

```
required.value("");
```

Now if you want to append any thing to already selected list, you can do what @OnaBai has show his snippet.

That's all it is there to the widget :)

Hope this was useful.

Comment: You face a strange problem when trying to add values to the already selected values. (Which case you don't handle in your examples.) You can't simply alter the array returned by .value(). You need to create a new array!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I struggled with is even after I had the answer. My Kendo Grid had over 6,000 items to select from. It was working most of the time. It was just when I updated the selection it was causing me issues.

The following code resolved my issue:

```
// Remove previous selected Filters. (This was undocumented method. I got from Kendo)
multiSelect.dataSource.filter({});

// Set the new filters
multiSelect.value(newlySelectedFilters);
```

Comment: It's documented now: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/multiselect#methods-value